# Background image is not showing in IE and works fine with other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Background image is not showing in IE and works fine with other browsers.

My line of code in CSS:

```
background: url(../images/box.png)no-repeat;
```

Comment: in which IE version ?

Comment: I think that it is because you have no space between `)` and `no-repeat`. Try this: `background: url(../images/box.png) no-repeat;`

Answer (score 1):

Add a space between image src and no-repeat.

```
url(../images/box.png) no-repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

You should review background's [shorthand implementation](http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/):

```
background: (color) url(../images/box.png) no-repeat (position-x) (position-y);
                                        ^^^^^
                                     there needs to be 
                                     a space here too
```

I'd recommend moving to individual declaration if you aren't going to specify everything in the shorthand form of background, i.e.:

```
background-image: url(../images/box.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```